# Postgresql how to cast string to timestamp with different format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with a field in string which represent a date.
But in this field the date is in different format ... It's not a fix format.
I have format like that (I see wrong and very horrible format ...):

- 2019-05-25 03: 40:28
- 2023-01-07 03:09:57
- 10/10/2022 12:45

I need to do an order by to this field and so I need to cast it in timestamp.

So, when I try to cast to timestamp, I got an error of parse format.

Is there a method to parse without a specific format?
How can I do to have a field correctly formatted?

Comment: The only parse error I got was: `select '2019-05-25 03: 40:28'::timestamp; ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2019-05-25 03: 40:28"` and that was because of the space between `... : 4...` here `03: 40:28`.

Comment: Another good example why you should _never_ store date or timestamp values as strings.

Comment: Since this will be a torturous and slow process, it's best to do this *once*. 1) Update each row to use a standard format. 2) Convert the column from text to timestamp. Then going forward sorting by timestamp will be easy. Various programming languages have libraries which can ***guess*** at the format. You could use this to fetch and update each row. It will be slow, and only as accurate as the library. PostgreSQL has [`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-formatting.html), but you must tell it the format pattern. You can try various patterns until one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally check all string format in the database, and I create a CASE for each string format and I do a 'to_timestamp' with the good format.
This is a sample of what I do:

```
CASE
     WHEN date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$' THEN to_timestamp(date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
     WHEN date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}: \d{2}:\d{2}$' THEN to_timestamp(date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24: MI:SS')
     ELSE to_timestamp(date,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
END formatted_date
```

With the new formatted field, I can order the query and do what I want with correct date format.

Comment: But what happens when someone submits a date formatted as `MM-DD-YYYY`, or even `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM`? Basic need resolve your current data with consistent format then convert then convert to data type `timestamp`. At least add a timestamp column and use it.

Comment: Yes but in this case, I must query my Database one time for filter it and clean it.
It's a on shoot query so I don't care of other format. But you right if you need to execute a query mor than one time.